# Change auto increment id to last without Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django

I want to refresh auto increment 'order_id' from between rows to next of last row in database layer without Django ORM.
my 'order_id' field is integer and it's auto increment in MySQL
for example I have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
and I want update 'order_id' from 3 to 6 id without get last 'order_id' with Django ORM.
is it possible?

My model is like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
     order_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` guarantees uniqueness, nothing else.  Don't use it if you need any other semantics for the id.

Furthermore, explicitly changing such ids may interfere with the above guarantee; beware.

Comment: `def refresh_order_id(self):
        last_order = Order.objects.order_by('create_at').last()
        self.order_id = last_order.order_id + 1
        self.save()` i need something like this in database level because if an order is created during the refresh, I get into trouble

Comment: "Refresh" is not a database operation; please explain.